# How to prove $bc \le ad \Rightarrow b+c < a+d$ for $b,c \in (a,d)$ and $a \ge 1$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $1 \le a<d$ and $b,c \in (a,d)$, the open interval.

*Question:* How to prove that $bc \le ad \Rightarrow  b+c < a+d$?

Comment: I think {a,d} is what you intended, as per the question body - I've corrected in the title.

Comment: @RobertFrost: yes, the open interval $(a,d)$.

Comment: ah ok my bad, I thought you meant a or d.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean $a\geq 1$ ?  As otherwise the asker has missed an opportunity there to make it a bit more tricky!

Comment: @RobertFrost: yes I mean  $a \ge 1$, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Suppose $bc \le ad$. Then:

$ a+d \ge d + \frac {bc}{d} \ge b + c$

The last inequality is true because:

$d + \frac {bc}{d} \ge b + c$ equivalent $d^2+bc \ge db +dc$ equivalent $d(d-b) \ge c(d-b)$

Actually the implication is true for all positive $a, b, c, d$ such that $d \ge b$ and $d \ge c$.

Comment: Very nice!  There is a list of problems like that for any integer $n$. You have solved the problem for $n=2$. Can you apply your method to solve the problem for $n=3$: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948132/84284  ?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Please don't alter my answer

Comment: Sorry... For having the strict inequality, we  just need $(d - b)(d-c)>0$ .

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Right, but I extended the hypothesis, that's why I considered also the equality case.

Comment: Your implication is also true for $d \le b$ and $d \le c$. For $a,b,c,d$ positive, it is true iff $(d−b)(d−c) \ge 0$

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes, that is correct