# Solvability of a system related to the subsets of {1,2,3}, II

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, systems-of-equations, lattice-orders

In the first post: [Solvability of a system related to the subsets of {1,2,3}](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948132/84284), we have shown ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950465/84284)) that an *allowed* labeling $f$ of $B_3$ can have a negative Euler totient $\varphi(f)$ [equals for example to $-1/4 + 3/100$ for $f$ below].

[image]

We have also proved that for any *allowed* labeling $f$ of $B_3$ then $\varphi(f) > -1$.

So the natural question is now the following:
Question: What's the infimum of $\{ \varphi(f) \mid f$ an *allowed* labeling $f$ of $B_3 \}$? Is it $-1/4$? What's the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mathematica, this infimum is exactly $-1/4$:

> In[1]:= FindMinimum[{x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 - 1,    x1 > x2
>   && x1 > x3 && x1 > x4 && x2 > x5 && x2 > x6 && x3 > x5 &&     x3 > x7
>   && x4 > x6 && x4 > x7 && x5 > 1 && x6 > 1 && x7 > 1 &&     x2 x3 <= x1
>   x5 && x2 x4 <= x1 x6 && x3 x4 <= x1 x7 && x5 x6 <= x2 &&
>       x5 x7 <= x3 && x6 x7 <= x4}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7}]
>
> Out[1]= {-0.25, {x1 -> 2.25, x2 -> 1.5, x3 -> 1.5, x4 -> 1.5,    x5 ->
>   1., x6 -> 1., x7 -> 1.}}

This infimum is not realized but the answer of the previous post
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950465/84284
gives a sequence $f_n$ such that $\varphi(f_n)$ converges to the infimum: take $x=9/4$ and $\epsilon_n = 1/n$.